# How do i take user input in php for two dimensional (2D) array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm completely new to PHP and can't understand how to take the user input for two-dimensional arrays (2D arrays). I'm providing you with the code I've been trying. Can anyone help me?

```
<?php

//$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$n= 0;
$m= 0;
fscanf("%d", $n);
fscanf("%d", $m);
$a = array(n)(m);
for($i=0 ; $i < $n ; $i++){
    for($j=0 ; $j < $m ; $j++ ){
        fscanf("%d", $a[$i][$j]);
    }
}


//fclose($handle);
?>
```

I expect to take input and print the array

Comment: Can you provide your STDIN please?

Comment: `3
3
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9`

Comment: I see its an array of `mxn` which are `rowsxcols`. and are they fixed? if yes what are values of m and n?

Comment: value of m=3 and n=3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Comment: You need to give the resource as first parameter `fscanf($handle,'%d',$m);`

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar I have put that as a comment actually, don't want to use file

Comment: as per PHP manual `The function fscanf()  takes its input from a file associated with handle and interprets the input according to the specified format, which is described in the documentation for sprintf().`

Comment: Ok. I'll try and revert here.

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar i tried this
`$n= 0;
$m= 0;
fscanf($handle,'%d',$n);
fscanf($handle,'%d',$m);
$a = array(n)(m);
for($i=0 ; $i < $n ; $i++){
    for($j=0 ; $j < $m ; $j++ ){
        fscanf($handle,'%d',$a[$i][$j]);
    }
}`  
I'm getting the same result of run-time error.

Comment: @LaxmikantKharangate Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the tested snippet,

```
$f    = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
// read whole string for manipulation
$line = fgets($f);
// exploding data with spaces
$arr  = explode(" ", $line);
$m    = $arr[0]; // first int as m rows 
$n    = $arr[1]; // second int as n cols
// unsetting as they are already used
unset($arr[0]);
unset($arr[1]);
// resetting index of array
$arr    = array_values($arr);
$result = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) {
        // fetching current value of array
        $result[$i][$j] = current($arr);
        // moving iterator to next element
        next($arr);
    }
}
fclose($f);
print_r($result);
```

[next](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) — Advance the internal pointer of an array
[current](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) — Return the current element in an array
[array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.
[fgets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) — Gets line from file pointer
[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) — Split a string by a string
[unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) — Unset a given variable

Output screen:

```
$:/var/www/html/dummy# php index.php
3 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9

        )

)
```